# Как вывести все слова из текста, содержащие заданную букву? с++

Tags: c++, строки

**Допустим мы вводим с клавиатуры текст "how long do humans live on this planet" и символ "p", а как итог получаем, что после выполнения кода в консоль выводит 3 буквы p, но не сами слова.**

*Формулировка задания: Выбрать и вывести на экран из заданного текста все слова, содержащие заданный символ*

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    const int SIZE = 100;
    char text[SIZE] = "\0";
    char letter[SIZE] = "\0";
    cout << "Введите текст\n";
    cin.getline(text, SIZE);
    cout << "Введите символ\n";
    cin.getline(letter, SIZE);
    cout << '\n';

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (text[i] == *letter)
            {
                cout << text[i] << '\n';
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Прошу дополнить мой код. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Дополнить не получится _  исправить нужно сначала.  Вы должны ввести один символ, а  вводите целую строку...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оператор ввода `>>` вводит строку до символа разделителя, так что при каждом вводе массива, вы введете именно одно слово, и будет вам счастье:

```
//вариант №1
const int SIZE = 100;
char text[SIZE];
cout << "Введите символ\n";
char letter;
cin >> letter;
cout << "Введите текст\n";
while (cin >> text) {
    if (strchr(text, letter))
        cout << text << '\n';
}
```

Но, далеко не всегда текст задается из потока ввода. Например строка может быть передана в аргумент функции из другого источника. Тогда будет другой подход.

```
//вариант№ 1.1
const std::string s = "how longp do humans live on this planet";
const char  c = 'p';      
size_t pos = s.find(c);
//пока не дошли до конца строки
//то есть такой символ есть  
while ( pos != s.npos)
{       
    size_t first = pos;
    //ищем начало слова       
    while (first && s[first] != ' ')
        --first;
    //ищем конец слова
    pos = s.find(' ', pos + 1);
    //если дошли до конца строки
    //установим pos как индекс конца строки
    if (pos == s.npos)
        pos = s.size();
    //теперь можем вывести
    cout << s.substr(first + 1, pos - first) << '\n';
    //если все же это не конец текста
    //ищем дальше
    if(pos != s.npos)
        pos = s.find(c, pos);
}
```

Тут вариантов решения и программирования можно написать десяток, но  решение задачи не дает ответа на конкретный вопрос, потому и бесполезны такие ответы и вопросы(разве что только для вас). Поэтому и этого достаточно для вашего изучения.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!